# Blazor - redirect to page in another project in one solution (i mean in one space for projects)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have situation where want to redirect user from page from one project to page in another project, in one solution. I want to go from LoginPanel to another project and want use static variable in another project but dont know how can do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdzVX.png)

Comment: What did you mean with `I want to use a static variable`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you can in App.razor page of LoginPanel project you can create an new assembly that refers to the project where is your page is exist like this:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="_exstraAssemeblies">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this page.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
</Router>
@code{
     public List<System.Reflection.Assembly> _exstraAssemeblies = new 
         List<System.Reflection.Assembly>
     {
       //TestMe can be any class in ProductManagementDatabase
        typeof(ProductManagementDatabase.TestMe).Assembly
     };
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, I want start new project in the same window